# In JavaScript, is there a word to describe a JSON-serializable object?

Tags: javascript, json, terminology, code-complexity

I'm looking for a term for simple objects that emphasizes their simplicity.  Specifically, objects that are free of self-reference, and contain no methods, bindings, etc (i.e. JSON-serializable).

Right now I use words like:

1. "flat object"
2. "simple object"
3. "data container object"
4. "JSON-serializable object"

I don't like them because:

1. Implies lack of hierarchy, which is actually fine.
2. Seems vague.
3. Also seems vague.
4. Not a direct reference to complexity, more an emphasis on requirements.  It isn't often that JSON-serializability is actually a requirement, while simplicity is.

#### Examples of objects I'm looking to describe:

```
var good_1 = {};

var good_2 = {a: 1, b: 'str'}

var good_3 = {thing: [1,
                      {a: 1,
                       b: 'str'},
                      'word'],
              otherThing: 42};
```

#### Examples of objects I want to differentiate from:

```
var bad_1 = {thing: 3,
             getThing: function () { return this.thing; }};

var bad_2 = {a: 1};
bad_2['self'] = bad_2;
```

#### Question

**What should I call objects that are free of self-reference, and contain no methods, bindings, etc (i.e. JSON-serializable)?**

Comment: The word "complexity" is pretty vague. "JSON-serializable" seems perfect because it's exactly what you're worried about. There are other serialization schemes, you know, that might have different rules from JSON as to what can be included and what can't.

Comment: Interesting...I normally just call them objects - no need to go past that - but that's my opinion.

Comment: @Pointy, exactly.  The vagueness of "complexity" and "simplicity" is what I want to avoid by using an unambiguous term, even if it's jarogny. "JSON-serializable" is technically unambiguous, but I'm curious if I can avoid its requirements connotation when I'm documenting my code.  I hope some programmer who's as pedantic as I am can tell me about an object complexity class hierarchy that my google queries aren't turning up :-)

Comment: Since we have used these things before than JSON (officially) came up, I wouldn't call them 'JSON something'. In my team we rather use terms like `entity or object structure or definition` and don't care how complex or how nested they might be.

Comment: How about just "serializable". Serializing in other languages can't handle functions, references, etc. AFAIK. So in broad terms it describes the kind of objects/structures what you speak of. :)

Comment: Yes JSON-serializable seems to be the best word to describe them ... Here is a javascript function that tests if the object is json-serializable `function isJSON(obj) { for(key in obj) if(typeof(obj[key])=="function") return false; return true; }`

Comment: @hex494D49, I like that you go a different direction than serializability, but I specifically care about complexity.  No self-reference, no methods. Just hierarchical data.

Comment: @undefined, thanks!  That's approaching what I want. A language-independent term would be perfect.  But in source documentation, if one reads '`returns a serializable object`', they may start asking, "why serializable? where are they serializing things?".  If actual serialization isn't relevant, then those questions are red herrings.  Ideally, one would read something like '`returns an <adjective> object`', where <adjective> means "of serializable complexity" with a definition in some googlable part of the internet.

Comment: @Khalid, that fails for self-reference.  If I actually needed such a function, I would just wrap a try/catch around `JSON.stringify()` and return the correct boolean.

Comment: @kdbanman Isn't it up to you to define in the documentation what a `serializable` object is, and why it's being used as a datatype in your code?

Comment: @undefined, you're right, that definition could totally go in a spec's glossary.  I was just curious if there was a sufficient term that's already accepted in some domain or another.

Comment: I'd call it "an element of the domain of `JSON.stringify`".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Plain Old Data Structure.**

PODS, for short.  They're a data structure comprised of only data fields, no behaviour.  The term is language-agnostic.

Context: they're often mentioned in the same breath as POJOs (Plain Old Java Objects), which vary a bit in definition.  [This wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure) says they're essentially PODS with getters and setters.  Some googling will turn up disagreement, though.

Answer (score 1):

[The Wikipedia article on serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) describes it as:

> In computer science, in the context of data storage, serialization is the process of translating data structures or object state into a format that can be stored and reconstructed later in the same or another computer environment. When the resulting series of bits is reread according to the serialization format, it can be used to create a semantically identical clone of the original object. For many complex objects, such as those that make extensive use of references, this process is not straightforward. Serialization of object-oriented objects does not include any of their associated methods with which they were previously inextricably linked.

So a *serializable* object pretty much describes the type of object you show in your question, not only in Javascript but in other languages as well.

Comment: This answer contradicts the definition it quotes. Serialization of circular data structures, though "not straightforward", is possible. The `bad_2` example absolutely is serializable, just not by `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: You can also serialize/unserialize `bad_1` using `toString` and the `Function` constructor, but most of the times calling "objects that are free of self-reference, and contain no methods, bindings, etc" serializable is fine.

Comment: By "fine" I mean that calling them serializable in broad terms is ok. Most of the times serializing an object doesn't include methods and/or references (at least in Javascript and PHP).